# Access function variable inside class method

Tags: php, slim

I searched and there are a lot of answers but I cannot find one I need because I do not know even how to create correct question. here is the example.

```
$app->map('/v1/:module/:group/:action(/:id)', function ($module, $group, $action, $id = NULL) use ($app) {

    $method = ucfirst($app->request->getMethod());
    $file = "modules/{$module}/{$group}/{$method}{$action}.php";

    if(!file_exists($file)) {
        $app->halt(404, Error::_('API Processor was not found!', 404));
    }

    include_once $file;

    $app->stop();
})
```

This is my API method by slim restful framework. Now for this `Error::_('API Processor was not found!', 404)` I have

```
class Error {
    public static function _($msg, $code = 500) {
        global $module, $group, $action;

        return json_encode(array(
            'error' => true,
            'code' => $code,
            'message' => $msg,
            'module' => $module
        ));
    }
}
```

What I want os to get access to `$module, $group, $action` variables without passing them into that function. But in my case `$module` is `NULL`.

```
{
    "error":true,
    "code":404,
    "message":"API Processor was not found!",
    "module":null
}
```

Possible?

Comment: Those aren't globals, and avoid global scope as much as possible. Feed the data you want your `_`  function to have (either explictly like `function _($msg, $code = 500,$module='')`, or a 3rd parameter with an array of variable data you might want your `Error::_()` to have.

Comment: That is a lot of coding. I wanted to make simple neat method to trigger errors.

Comment: The amount of coding is limited, especially if you go for the 3rd parameter as an array and just feed it with `get_defined_vars()`. This is a _lot_ easier to maintain, debug, and write, then trying to break apart the entire scope implementation in PHP. Scope is good, it is your friend. If you don't want to change your function's signature, you could go for `Error::_("API Processor was not found, tried to load $file.");`, which will have the date human readable in your error message, but granted: less structured.

Comment: I supposed to call this helper function all over. Even in other helper classes. To make sure that those variable always passed everywhere is complicated and may lead to buggy application.

Comment: Breaking scope would lead to an even more unmaintainable application. To make sure variables always get passed is... easier. If you are saying: I am going to use this in helper functions which don't have access to the current `$module` or some variable I'm interested in, more apt would be to think the other way around: why would a helper function _call_ this function? It probably is not its responsibility. You might me better of throwing exceptions at that point, and make sure the code _catching_ it is at a place where they _do_ have access to the data you're interested in.

Comment: Yes, this is what I end up right now. Just throw an exception.

Comment: Which would be the proper way to do it. Keep in mind that: (1) you can extend exceptions with custom variables and/or data and (2) you can catch an exception, add some data and rethrow it. So, you could still make sure that every step on the way adds the local variable you feel you need along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be able to meet those requirements, if I understood your question correctly, by using the [Slim Error Handling](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Error-Handling-Overview) functionality. If it were my project, I'd create a custom exception to throw wherever you're planning on using your custom error function.

***NOTE***: All of the code below is untested and written off the top of my head. Caveat emptor and all that.

```
class CustomErrorException extends \Exception
{
}
```

Then I would throw that exception wherever I'd otherwise use my custom error function.

```
if(!file_exists($file)) {
    throw new CustomErrorException('API Processor was not found!', 404);
}
```

Finally, I'd write an error function that looks something like this:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e) use ($app) {

    if ($e instanceof CustomErrorException) {
        // Parse $path to get $module, $group, and $action
        // (Seems like that would work based on the route in your example: '/v1/:module/:group/:action(/:id)')
        $path = $app->request->getPath();

        // Possible new method signature for Error::_
        Error::_($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $module, $group, $action);

        // Render an error page, $app->halt(), whatever.
    }
});
```

That should help [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code up a bit and allow you to dump those `global` variables.

Comment: > // Parse $path to get $module, $group, and $action

Thid id the problem. There is no way to get route parameters. I can only get URL or request or get or post parameters. But no access to route variables. It is only passed to function when you set route. Otherwise I would not have this question at all.

Comment: Then you can add an array property to your custom exception and `getRouteParams` and `setRouteParams` methods. Then you'll have the route params in the error handler. Just off the top of my head.

Comment: Actually that's not true. You should be able to get route params from `$app->request->params()`.